# in creating a subclass i am getting an error that there is an error with my formal parameter (get and set are set)

Tags: c#

I have a get and set set in class of sportsTeam but in Basketball when I am trying to set inherited parameters it says it says "there is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal paramenter.

I have tried playing with some of the parameters and followed my text book almost exactly. I cannot find what I am missing.

```
    //sportsTeam.cs
        public class sportsTeam
    {       private string coach;
            private int numberOfPlayers;
            private string seasonPlayed;
            private string field;
            private string practiceDays;

    public sportsTeam(string inCoach, int inNumberOfPlayers, string 
    inSeasonPlayed, string inField, string inPracticeDays)
        {
            coach = inCoach;
            numberOfPlayers = inNumberOfPlayers;
            seasonPlayed = inSeasonPlayed;
            field = inField;
            practiceDays = inPracticeDays;

        }

        public String inCoach
        {
            get { return coach;  }
            set { coach = value; }
        }

        public int inNumberOfPlayers
        {
            get { return numberOfPlayers; }
            set { numberOfPlayers = value; }
        }

        public String inSeasonPlayed
        {
            get { return seasonPlayed;  }
            set { seasonPlayed = value;  }
        }

        public String inField
        {
            get { return field;  }
            set { field = value;  }
        }

        public String inPracticeDays
        {
            get { return practiceDays;  }
            set { practiceDays = value;  }
        }
    }

//basketball.cs
public class basketball : sportsTeam
{
    private String ballSupplier;
    private String renetter;

public basketball(string inSeasonPlayed, string inField, string inPracticeDays, string inBallSupplier, string inRenetter)
    :base(inSeasonPlayed, inField, inPracticeDays) //Error is here
{
    inBallSupplier = ballSupplier;
    inRenetter = renetter;
}
```

}

Comment: I suggest to remove all those local variables and use [Auto Implemented Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties)

Answer (score 3):

Your parent class constructor have 5 parameters:

```
public sportsTeam(string inCoach, int inNumberOfPlayers, string 
    inSeasonPlayed, string inField, string inPracticeDays)
```

while when you are calling it form the child/ dervied class you are only providing 3 and there is no constructor overload in your parent class with 3 parameters.

See:

```
public basketball(string inSeasonPlayed, string inField, string inPracticeDays, string inBallSupplier, string inRenetter)
    :base(inSeasonPlayed, inField, inPracticeDays) // 3 parameters while it requires 5
```

You need to provide all the 5 parameters of constructor or  create a constructor overload depending on what is your requirement.

You can define another constructor overload in `sportsTeam` like following :

```
public sportsTeam(string inSeasonPlayed, 
                  string inField, 
                  string inPracticeDays)
{
    seasonPlayed = inSeasonPlayed;
    field = inField;
    practiceDays = inPracticeDays;

}
```

You can read more about [Constructors and Inheritance here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/inheritance-and-constructors-in-c-sharp).

Answer (score 0):

Create this constructor in base class

```
public sportsTeam(string inSeasonPlayed, string inField, string inPracticeDays)
        {
            this.inSeasonPlayed = inSeasonPlayed;
            this.inField = inField;
            this.inPracticeDays = inPracticeDays;
        }
```